# Laravel 5.1 localization

Tags: php, laravel, localization

I am quite new to Laravel so I am still missing some good programming practices. For my work I need localization of app in 3 languages.

I know where to make language files resources/lang... To use them I can write `Lang::get('navigation.dining')`. And in my view file at the beginng I define `<?php App::setLocale(session('lang'));?>`.

Session is saved routes.php. Here is an example :

```
Route::get('language/{lan?}', function ($lan='eng'){
    Session::put('lang', $lan);
    return redirect()->back();
});
```

I am not sure if this approach is good or not, so please correct it or suggest best way to do it.

Comment: This is one method yes. It all depends on how your application should work. Your code suggests a visitor will select a language from a dropdown and get redirected to this page, sessions variable is set and the visitor will get redirected back. Seems legit.

Comment: The part of code that concerns me most is this one : `App:setLocale(session('lang'));` because I am using it at the begginng of each view. This is something I am not sure about if  its good.

Comment: yes it's better to keep application logic in the controllers or better yet in a service provider instead of defining it at the top of your view/template

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for either of these:

```
app()->setLocale($lan);
App::setLocale($lan);
```

Best practice would be to put them in a Language Middleware.